# How can I specify an admin fee in PayPal when ordering less than 2 items?

Tags: paypal

This is my first time using PayPal to handle payments from a website, and I am struggling to get my client's business model to work with PayPal's Website Payments Standard.

Basically the way that each order works is that if the customer orders only 1 tour, there is a single person supplement of £250.

Any thoughts on how I would add this to the checkout?

My best attempt is to add a "handling" fee of £250, and give a discount of £250 if the customer orders more than 1 tour.

For example...

```
<input name="amount" value="750" />
<input name="handling" value="250" />
<input name="discount_amount" value="0" />
<input name="discount_amount2" value="250" />
<input name="discount_num" value="1" />
```

This works technically, but it means that the customer is presented with a line item on their bill that reads "Postage and Packaging". I would rather it read "Single Supplement Fee" or "Admin Fee".

Any help and advice would be very welcome.

Comment: I feel this question is programming related and therefore I am quite upset that it has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered an intermediary page that the first form gets posted to and that has the logic of "if more than 1 tour" and adjusts the product title and full pricing before sending on to PayPal?

Comment: I never considered that. Thank you for that idea. I will see what I can do with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a 'discount' line item worth -£250 when you can detect 2+ tours?